# Constructor in a custom entity isn't prior to baseFieldDefinitions

Tags: 8, entities

I have a custom entity with a constructor that calls a custom method (generateCharacteristics()) to generate random values for certain fields of my entity :

```
    public function __construct(array $values, $entity_type, $bundle = FALSE, $translations = array()) {

    parent::__construct($values, $entity_type, $bundle = FALSE, $translations = array());

    $values += $this->generateCharacteristics();

    foreach ($values as $key => $value)
    {

        $method = 'set'.ucfirst($key);

        // For two-words attributes
        if( strstr($method, '_') ) {
            $method = explode('_', $method);
            $method[1] = ucfirst($method[1]);
            $method = implode('', $method);
        }

        if (method_exists($this, $method))
        {
          $this->$method($value);
        }
    }


}
```

When I log what occurs in this __construct method when I create a new entity, all works fine, attributes are well setted, but in my database I have NULL or default values (the ones I declared in baseFieldDefinitions()). That's a shame because I think that baseFieldDefinitions() is put in cache (not good for random values) and that my method using constructor is cleaner.

Maybe my error is to think that $values array is the array we send during the call of Entity::create() method because this $values array seems always empty before I add my own array to $values... Nevertheless I set my attributes correctly in the constructor. The use of a postCreate() method should be more appropriate ?

thanks !

Comment: There's a lot happening in the parent constructor (You should take a look). Try running `parent::_construct` after `$values += $this->generateCharacteristics();`. I don't think you even need to call those setter methods. It should get set in the parent constructor.

Comment: You do save the entity right? Just creating it only instantiates the entity, but it is gone once the request ends. You have to call `Entity::save()` separately. Since you say it works when you inspect it, I figured this might be the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Entity::create` gets the storage for the entity type and calls  [EntityStorage::create](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageInterface.php/function/EntityStorageInterface%3A%3Acreate/8.4.x). What you are looking for is probably the method 
[Entity::preCreate](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3ApreCreate/8.4.x), which is the first entity event invoked by `EntityStorage::create`.

Place it as public static function in the custom entity class to change the values before the entity is created:

```
class CustomEntity extends ContentEntityBase {

   /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function preCreate(EntityStorageInterface $storage, array &$values) {
    // modify $values
  }

}
```